# qt, is this the safe way to use deleteLater?

Tags: c++, qt

Qt said the deleteLater is called after the event loop returns.
So, if I have the following code:

```
 Waypoint* wp = new Waypoint();
 WaypointWidget* wp_widget = new WaypointWidget(wp);
 ...
 delete wp;
 wp_widget->deleteLater();
 ...
 Waypoint* wp2 = new Waypoint();
 WaypointWidget* wp_widget2 = new WaypointWidget(wp2);
```

the constructor of WaypointWidget is:

```
WaypointWidget(Waypoint* wp){
  _wp = wp;//_wp is declared as private variable inside WaypointWidget.h
}
```

My concern is that, for some situation, the *wp2* will take the same address as the *wp*, and when the deleteLater() cause the *wp_widget* is finally deleted.The corresponding *_wp* will be deleted. And because it has the same address as *wp2*. The *wp2* will be deleted/affected.

Answer (score 2):

You call `deleteLater` for wp_widget, not for `wp`, so same address will not be set. Possible error will be if you will try to access `_wp` in `WaypointWidget` destructor.

I recommend you to read about RAII.

Comment: I have checked RAII on wikibooks...But I still don't understand why wp2 will never get the same address as wp(the address of wp before it is deleted)

Comment: wp2 gets new address because you assign it *new* `Waypoint()`.

Comment: If I understand @Nyaruko concerns, as we have deleted the wp instance that memory is now free which if the memory allocator feels so can be given for the newer wp2 instance. After this the event loop will pick up wp_widget deletion event and call its destructor. Are you deleting _wp in the destructor of the widget ? Can you show the code for WaypointWidget destructor and member declaration of _wp ?

Comment: No, I am not deleting it inside the destructor. The destructor of WaypointWidget is a default one. like ~WaypointWidget(){}

Comment: @Nyaruko Then why do you assume that `_wp` will be deleted?

Comment: I thought there might be a chance: wp has address, say 0xf123456 after it is deleted, wp2 is also assigned with address 0xf123456. Then what will happen in this case?

Comment: @Nyaruko Unless you do something with it, nothing.

Comment: So, if I don't dereference the _wp during deconstruction, it is safe?

Comment: If it's untouched after it's been deleted then it might be safe, but it's still not the right way of doing it. `WaypointWidget` should take ownership of `Waypoint`. `WaypointWidget` should be the one that deletes `WayPoint`. `WayPoint` shouldn't be deleted from outside of `WaypointWidget`.